# KVM GPU passthrough of nVidia dGPU on laptop with hybrid graphics without proprietary drivers on host

Tags: virtual-machine, gpu, linux-kvm

I have a 2017 Dell XPS 9560 with a discrete nVidia graphics card in addition to integrated Intel graphics. The nVidia card is usually powered down by way of an ACPI command. I do not have, or want, the propietary nVidia drivers on my main system. However, I would really like to use CUDA. Can I do GPU passthrough to a KVM guest runnining the proprietary drivers?

Most resources I've found seem to assume that the host is running the proprietary drivers and Bumblebee, but I haven't been able to assertain whether this is necessary or not.

Answer (score 5):

1. Verify if your nVidia graphics card is MUXed or MUXless.  If you can find BIOS option to choose "integrated graphics" and "PCI graphics" (Whatever name), then it is MUXed.  Else is MUXless.
2. If it is MUXed, you can follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/Misairu-G/616f7b2756c488148b7309addc940b28).
3. If it is MUXless, you can follow [enter link description here](https://github.com/jscinoz/optimus-vfio-docs) but this is highly technical and insufficient details to follow.

For first case, about 2 guys success in the world.  For second case, only 1 guy who drafted the guide success.  Good luck.

Comment: Don't both of those assume that the *host* uses the proprietary nVidia drivers?